# How to remove the table name at the child?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```js
const result = await Article.findAll({
        include:{
            model:User,
            attributes:[['username','author']]
        },
        where:{deleted:0},
        attributes: ['id','title','description','keywords','content','tabId','createdAt','updatedAt'],
        order:[
            ['id','desc']
        ],
        raw:true
    })
    console.log(result)
```

[Search results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4WjX.png)

I added a `raw:true` make the child param on the same layer.

but it got a prefix `User.`.

how to remove it.

Comment: What about just map it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to remove the User prefix since you have included a join inside your include option.

**Suggestions** :

1. Add `nest: true` instead of the option `raw:true` for your query, which will convert it from an alias to an object. This will help you achieve a cleaner result.

```
const result = await Article.findAll({
  include: {
    model: User,
    attributes: [['username', 'author']],
  },
  where: { deleted: 0 },
  attributes: [
    'id',
    'title',
    'description',
    'keywords',
    'content',
    'tabId',
    'createdAt',
    'updatedAt',
  ],
  order: [['id', 'desc']],
  nest: true, <=======
});
```

2. You can add an alias for your join, this way you have control over your prefix by providing the `as` operator inside your associations
   please visit the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/) for more info